# Replace some characters in a column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I need to remove some characters and replace them from others.
Like in a column I need to replace

I need to replace column text from "data&data&sometext" to "data&sometext".

Something like

```
UPDATE TABLE 
SET Column = "data&sometext"
WHERE Column = "data&data&sometext"
```

Comment: You are done man! What's the question?

Comment: Sorry I believe I made it not so clear.
Thing is to find that pattern in where clause say how I will find data in column where we have say two(2) occurrences of "data&" and how to replace it with only "data&"

Comment: What is the exact rule for what you are looking for and what you want to replace it with?  Does it involve the & symbol?

Comment: Yes it involves "&" symbol... the data in my column is something like... "data&data&sometext" where "data" and "sometext" can be anything. From my name to your name or some kind of sequence of numbers of anything

Answer (score 0):

Well, try this:

```
UPDATE TABLE 
SET Column = REPLACE(Column, 'data&data&', 'data&')
WHERE Column LIKE 'data&data&%';
```

**UPDATE:**

So, based on your comment, try this:

```
UPDATE TABLE
SET Column = REPLACE([Column], LEFT([Column], CHARINDEX('&', [Column], CHARINDEX('&', [Column]) + 1)), LEFT([Column], CHARINDEX('&', [Column])))
WHERE Column LIKE LEFT([Column], CHARINDEX('&', [Column], CHARINDEX('&', [Column]) + 1)) + '%'
```

Comment: Apologies again...
It is not that simple "data&data&" is not a hardcoded value it can be anything in place of "data".

Say data can be anything "ashish&ashish&" or "13213&13213&" or "men&men&"

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE TABLE 
SET Column = REPLACE(Column , 'data&data&sometext', 'data&sometext')
WHERE Column LIKE '%data&data&sometext%'
```